# I am trying to install the Cell Typist package in Python 3.10.9 and I keep running into a legacy-install-failure error

Tags: python, annoy

When i tried using pip install celltypist, an error kept showing up related to problems in installing the package annoy. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TVXS.png)

I even updated my Microsoft Visual Studio for C++ and it did not affect the issue. It keeps showing a legacy-install-failure error statement every time i try to install annoy or celltypist

Comment: Please paste the error here instead of linking to an image.